# How to define all aspects of a new UIvariable in creation?

Tags: swift, aspects

Im creaing a Program in swift where I have a "Test.swift" with a class containing some static variable. One of these variables is a `UITextField` created like this :

```
static var textField1 : UITexField = UITextField()
```

The next thing I would now like to do is give this textField1 some aspects such as font and background colore such as this

```
static var textField1 : UITexField = UITextField()

Test.textField1.tintColor = UIColor.yellow()
```

It wount let me do this though because im nof in a function im still in the bare class, now I had the idea of creating a static function which than adds all the aspect and returns the finished Text Field, but I would rather do it somewhat like this :

```
static var textField1 : UITexField = UITextField(tintColor = UIColor.brown(), Font = etc.)
```

is this somehow achievable ?

Comment: You can only declare a `UITextField` with a `frame` or `NSCoder`, I suggest you to create your own subclass of `UITextField` and init it with your own parameters.

Comment: Um, this is not true. You can use `extension` keyword to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use extensions?

```
extension UITextField {
    static func textFieldWithFont(font : UIFont, tintColor : UIColor) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.tintColor = tintColor
        textField.font = font
        return textField
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
let textField = UITextField.textFieldWithFont(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17), tintColor: UIColor.yellowColor())
```